# Umbraco contour and google apps email

Tags: gmail, umbraco, contour, umbraco-contour

I can't seem to get the contour package with umbraco working with google mail as the smtp server (I think its a SSL issue).  Has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced problems with Google Mail SSL SMTP servers in the past. There seem to be 2 port options for you to use. I think you need to use port 587 not the default 468.

Google Mail server details:
http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=78799

Answer (score 1):

I have just submitted an update to the [Contour Contrib](http://contourcontrib.codeplex.com/) project that adds support for turning on SSL which is required as mentioned above.

Until the download has been updated you will just need to download and compile the source and copy the release folder into your Umbraco solution, this will give you a new Workflow type "email, extended" which you then use instead of the standard "email" workflow type.

For Gmail you will need the following settings in web.config:

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" userName="youruser@yourdomain.com" password="yourpassword" port="587" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

You will also need to add the following line to the appSettings section of the web.config

```
<add key="contourContribUseSsl" value="true" />
```

Cheers,

Chris